# Log user IP with PHP

Tags: php

Currently I'm using this script to log my users IP adresses:

```
    $userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

However, after I bought a Anti-DDoS HTTP Proxy, it returns the proxy IP instead.

```
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] -> 198.12.12.102
```

I'm using Cloudflare with the proxy, so I've entered the Proxy's IP inside the IP field in Cloudflare and then selected 'Bypass the Cloudflare network'.

Comment: That's nice. Did you have a question?

Comment: And What is your question?

Comment: There's no question being asked.


Comment: The question is the title.

Comment: The title is not a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes, if the request is proxied, all PHP sees is the proxy's address. In this case, **and only in this case**, should you look at alternative HTTP headers. The proxy may, *should*, add the original IP address as an extra HTTP header, like `X-Forwarded-For`, which will be available in `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`.

Usually it's a security risk to pay attention to these headers; only if you know that *your* proxy that *you* control explicitly adds this header on *your behalf* should you use it.

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] actually does return the IP address! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Reverse proxies may store the original user's IP in a HTTP header. Dump the request headers to see if this is the case. If there is no such header there's nothing you can do.

REMOTE_ADDR is the address of the system that made the actual socket connection to your server. If proxies are involved you should expect to see proxy IP.